# How do I allocate memory for LabVIEW array of clusters using DSSetHandleSize() without a memory exception

Tags: memory-management, dll, labview

I am able to reliably use `DSSetHandleSize()` with arrays of LabVIEW strings. When I try the same with arrays of clusters, it always crashes upon return from the DLL when increasing the handle size.

The code is:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t depth;
    LStrHandle name;
    LStrHandle child;
    } TreeElem;
typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSize;
    TreeElem Element[1];
    } **TreeHdl;

MSEXPORT void BuildTreeCtl(int32_t depth, uint32_t xmlNodePtr, TreeHdl TreeCluster)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node, *chile_node;

    for (cur_node = (xmlNode *) xmlNodePtr; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
        
        if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            DSSetHandleSize(TreeCluster, sizeof(int32) + (sizeof(TreeElem) * ((*TreeCluster)->dimSize + 1)));
            int idx = (*TreeCluster)->dimSize++;
             
            if (cur_node->name != NULL) {
                    LV_STR_NEW(((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx].name, (char*) cur_node->name);}
            //  check for CDATA
            for (chile_node = cur_node->children; chile_node; chile_node = chile_node->next) {
                if (chile_node->type == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
                    if (chile_node->content != NULL) {
                            LV_STR_NEW(((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx].child, (char*) chile_node->content);
                    }
                }
            }
            BuildTreeCtl(depth + 1, (uint32_t) cur_node->children, TreeCluster);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call DSSetHSzClr instead of DSSetHandleSize.

Comment: Ouch. You'd think there'd be mention of clearing the data or a reference to `DSSetHSzClr()`, but they only refer to  `NumericArrayResize()`.  I'll put that one squarely on NI and bad documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `DSSetHandleSize()` (*for at least LabVIEW 2013 and earlier*) does not initialize new memory to zero when increasing array size.  Also, it's likely to allocate a new block of memory with a different handle than when going in - it does reliably transfer existing data to the new memory allocation, but whatever exists in the new memory block will cause LabVIEW to crash on return, certainly because LabVIEW is using junk pointers.

The code should be:

```
MSEXPORT void BuildTreeCtl(int32_t depth, uint32_t xmlNodePtr, TreeHdl TreeCluster)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node, *chile_node;

    for (cur_node = (xmlNode *) xmlNodePtr; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
        
        if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            DSSetHandleSize(TreeCluster, sizeof(int32) + (sizeof(TreeElem) * ((*TreeCluster)->dimSize + 1)));
            int idx = (*TreeCluster)->dimSize++;
```

---

```
            #if 0   // brute force
                (((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx]).depth = depth;
                (((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx]).name = NULL;
                (((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx]).child = NULL;
            #elif 0 // generic
                uint8_t *Ptr = (uint8_t *) &(((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx]);
                for (int j=0; j<sizeof(TreeElem); j++) {*(Ptr + j) = 0;}
            #else
                uint8_t *Ptr = (uint8_t *) &(((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx]);
                memset(Ptr, 0, sizeof(TreeElem));       
            #endif
```

---

```
            if (cur_node->name != NULL) {
                    LV_STR_NEW(((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx].name, (char*) cur_node->name);}
            //  check for CDATA
            for (chile_node = cur_node->children; chile_node; chile_node = chile_node->next) {
                if (chile_node->type == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
                    if (chile_node->content != NULL) {
                            LV_STR_NEW(((*TreeCluster)->Element)[idx].child, (char*) chile_node->content);
                    }
                }
            }
            BuildTreeCtl(depth + 1, (uint32_t) cur_node->children, TreeCluster);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call DSSetHSzClr instead of DSSetHandleSize.